# Advantages of Action bar. Original Action bar Vs Action Bar Look And feel created using Layouts, Buttons & TextView

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I know `ActionBar` is something important in android design guidelines.

I've some doubts on this.

Why do we use this `ActionBar`?

We can also create the look and feel of an action bar using `Layouts`, `TextViews` & `Buttons`. Whats the difference between them(`ActionBar` & Action Bar Look And feel created using `Layouts`, `Buttons` & `TextView`)?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating own ActionBar (using layouts) is not a good and recommended way. ActionBar can have buttons, tabs, drop downs, contextual ActionBar items, progress bar, searchview, back button etc etc

Now If you need one or two or more of above things in your action bar, then it is very difficult to create own layouts and manage every thing, where as ActionBar (especially ActionBar Sherlock) will make your life easy.

Comment: thanks for your reply. is there any difference in performance of both?

Comment: It depends on situation but in general there will be no performance issue

Answer (score 1):

The action bar is a window feature that identifies the application and user location, and provides user actions and navigation modes. You should use the action bar in most activities that need to prominently present user actions or global navigation, because the action bar offers users a consistent interface across applications and the system gracefully adapts the action bar's appearance for different screen configurations. You can control the behaviors and visibility of the action bar with the [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html) APIs, which were added in Android 3.0 (API level 11).

The primary goals of the action bar are to:

- Provide a dedicated space for identifying the application brand and user location.
  This is accomplished with the app icon or logo on the left side and the activity title. You might choose to remove the activity title, however, if the current view is identified by a navigation label, such as the currently selected tab.
- Provide consistent navigation and view refinement across different applications.
  The action bar provides built-in tab navigation for switching between fragments. It also offers a drop-down list you can use as an alternative navigation mode or to refine the current view (such as to sort a list by different criteria).
- Make key actions for the activity (such as "search", "create", "share", etc.) prominent and accessible to the user in a predictable way.

  You can provide instant access to key user actions by placing items from the options menu directly in the action bar, as "action items." Action items can also provide an "action view," which provides an embedded widget for even more immediate action behaviors. Menu items that are not promoted to an action item are available in the overflow menu, revealed by either the device Menu button (when available) or by an "overflow menu" button in the action bar (when the device does not include a Menu button).

From:http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html